# Как равномерно вставить меньшее количество в большее?

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Как равномерно распределить меньшее количество элементов в большем их количестве? То есть у меня есть два множества элементов:

> oooooooooo(10)
>   ОООО(4)

Нужно объединить их так, чтобы они были равномерно распределены. Например вот так:

> ooОooОooОooОoo(14)

Разделение большего на меньшее даёт этот интервал. Почему это так и с чего начинается поиск решения?

Comment: Думаю, не хватает знаний примерно из программы 3 класса, когда проходят деление чисел.

Comment: Ну, может, человек из второго класса?))

Comment: "почему я туплю" - я задаю себе этот вопрос несколько раз в день (... или в час?)

Comment: @vp_arth да всё, я понял. 4-го курса неполного высшего хватило для того, чтобы я понял.

Comment: Что с краями делать? Нарисован линейный вариант, где неравномерно получилось: тем "О", что в середине, досталось всего по одной "о" с каждого бока. А крайние "О" счастливчики: им со стороны краёв дано по 2 "о", а со стороны центра по одной, как и всем. Может, рисовать их как замкнутый круг, и стараться вставить максимально равномерно (что не всегда достижимо, будут погрешности)

Comment: Ну кстати, в программировании постоянно такие задачки приходится решать... А в бекэнде так ещё и вышка пригождается. Все-таки в программировании нужна математика, но не сказать, что она какая-то жеская (опять же - смотря куда и как глубоко идти). Но если это вызывает затруднения, то... лучше не тратить уже время, а поискать вариант повкуснее (если лет уже больше 18-и, примерно).

Comment: Т.е. тем кто во фронтенде на вышке можно сэкономить?

Comment: Вам нужно именно равномерно, или случайно-равновероятно?

Answer (score 6):

Алгоритм такой:

- Делим "большее" на "меньшее+1" с "остатком".
- Вставляем "частное" количество `o`
- аккумулируем остатки, если сумма остатков переваливает единицу, добавляем лишнюю `o`
- Вставляем `O`
- Повторяем "меньшее" количество раз
- Прицепляем хвост из "частного" количества `o`

```js
let a = Math.random()*30+1;
let b = Math.random()*10+1;
[a, b] = [Math.min(a, b), Math.max(a, b)].map(x => Math.floor(x));
let [div, rem] = [Math.floor(b/(a+1)), b%(a+1)];

console.log('O'.repeat(a), a);
console.log('o'.repeat(b), b);

let res = '', acc = rem;
for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
  res += 'o'.repeat(div + +(acc>=a));
  res += 'O';
  acc = acc % a + rem;
}
res += 'o'.repeat(div);
console.log(res, res.length);
```

Comment: И не лень же было...

Comment: Ого, спасибо большое!) Только знания синтаксиса JS не даёт мне быстро вникнуть в ваш алгоритм..

Comment: Именно поэтому выше написан текст.

Comment: @vp_arth а скажите, картинки увеличиваются/уменьшаются по похожему принципу? Мы рассчитываем среднее между двумя пикселями и вставляем между ними новый? А количество новых пикселей определяется подобным выше принципом?

Comment: Нет, резервируется канва ресайзнутой картинки и цвет каждого её пикселя вычисляется по функции от соответсвующей окрестности оригинальной картинки. Функцией может быть, например, [Бикубическая интерполяция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Comment: @vp_arth ой, два пиксела маловато будет, конечно)) ладно, спасибо, что повозились..

Comment: Если заданный вами вопрос решён - отметьте правильный ответ - зелёная галочка под голосами.

Answer (score 4):

1. разделить меньшее *S* на большее *B*, получится некий дробный коэффициент *k* < 1;
2. завести счётчик *r*, начав с 0;
3. вставлять *B* и к счётчику *r* добавлять дробный *k*;
4. как только в *r* набегает >= 1, надо уменьшить *r* на 1, и пора вставить элемент *S*;
5. так до тех пор, пока не вставим все положенные элементы *B* и *S*.

**Интерактивная визуализация вставки:**

```js
var data=[],a,b;var svg=d3.select("body").append("div").append("svg").attr("width",160).attr("height",160);var g=svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(80,80)");var tr=d3.transition().duration(500).ease(d3.easeLinear);function movescale(c){c.attr("cx",function(d){return 70*Math.cos(d.i*2*Math.PI/(a+b));}).attr("cy",function(d){return 70*Math.sin(d.i*2*Math.PI/(a+b));}).attr("r",d=>""+(d.big?9:7)+"px").attr("style",d=>"fill:"+(d.big?"#F90":"#333"));}
function getoff(e){e.attr("cx",0).attr("cy",0).attr("r",0)}
update();function update(){var i,circle,B,S;a=parseInt(document.getElementById("in-A").value);b=parseInt(document.getElementById("in-B").value);B=Math.max(a,b);S=Math.min(a,b);data=[];var k=S/B,r=0;i=iB=iS=0;while(data.length<B+S){if(iB<B)data.push({i:i,id:"B"+iB,big:true}),i++,iB++;r+=k;if(r>=1){if(iS<S)data.push({i:i,id:"S"+iS,big:false}),i++,iS++;r-=1;}}
circle=g.selectAll("circle").data(data,d=>d.id);circle.exit().transition(tr).call(getoff).remove();circle.enter().append("circle").attr("r",0).transition(tr).call(movescale);circle.transition(tr).call(movescale);}
document.getElementById("in-A").addEventListener("input",update);document.getElementById("in-B").addEventListener("input",update);
```

```css
circle {stroke:white}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<input id="in-A" type="number" value=10>
<input id="in-B" type="number" value=4>
```

Не минифицированный [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/5x9mxdg4/).

Answer (score 2):

Знаете, надо разделить большее количество на меньшее, получить некоторое число N, а потом вставлять элементы из меньшего набора по одному в больший после каждых N элементов этого набора. Деление проводить с округлением в меньшую сторону, т.е. в последней группе у Вас может получиться не N, а меньше элементов. Тут уже смотрите Вашу задачу, что сказано на этот счет. Ахах

Comment: Но ведь делить нужно на меньшее+1....

Comment: куда вставить 1 элемент среди 10 – в которую из 11 позиций? (из 10 позиций, если расположить по кругу)